# Creating "wallets" for users with BlockCypher

Tags: bitcoin

I'm new to the world of Bitcoin, and I am having a hard time trying to understand the basics of wallet implementation for a basic bitcoin service.

**Basically, I'd like that:**

- Users have a personal wallet ("in-site" wallet, keeping track of their balance)
- Users are able to deposit/withdraw into/from that address/wallet
- The web service is able to make transactions on behalf of the user
  (to other addresses)

I know there are plenty of ways to go about this, and there are many APIs that can help, so I will narrow this problem down to using [BlockCypher's API](http://dev.blockcypher.com/#generate-address-endpoint), which I believe has many similarities with other APIs.

I'd just like to know the general steps one should take to implement this, since I'm pretty much lost. How do I start?

**I was thinking that the steps I should take are:**

- With the API, generate an address (server side?) and store the private and public keys in a database. Use the same address for the same user all the time.
- Use the transactions API to do the rest and keep track of Bitcoin balance.

**However, this put me off a bit (coming from BlockCypher's API, on address generation):**

> The private key returned is immediately discarded by our servers, but
> we advise that these keys should not be used for any high-value—or
> long-term storage—addresses.

The wallets I intend to use would be considered "long-term" storage, I guess, so what other way I could go about implementing such a system?

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, or if I'm misunderstanding. It'd be great to have some guidance on the right direction; of course I don't expect full-code examples, just an explanation of the concepts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bitcoin private key is essential to using the wallet. Bitcoin is based on the PGP idea - one private key corresponds to one public key.

The API that you are using immediately discards the private key, otherwise they would be able to spend the money in every wallet they generate. They would do this by creating transactions and signing them with the private keys that they had.

So they generate these private keys in memory, *send them to you via the API*, and then discard them. **BlockCypher's discarding the private keys does not impact your receipt of these keys.** You still get the keys via the API and will have them in memory on your server.

**You need to store these private keys** in persistent storage, such as a database. Once you do that, then you can transact on behalf of users.

In regards to the *long-term storage* aspect, they are referring to the strength of the private key used to generate the wallet. Given this, they are likely not extremely strong (it does not mean they are weak!). You want a strong private key so it is not easily hacked or guessed. For long-term storage, especially of high dollar amounts, those wallets are available on the blockchain and are a hacking target. For long-term storage, you're better off with a [Trezor](https://www.bitcointrezor.com/) or reading up on encryption (which is best done at [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clearer, I think. So then there's no benefit of using an API like BlockCypher's for something like this? I wanted to avoid handling the money directly on my servers (I guess storing the private keys is pretty much that), since I'm not a security expert. I thought they'd in some way store the private keys and I could manage transactions with the token they give. This is probably then off-topic, and I hope you don't mind me asking further questions, but what would you recommend I do if I don't want to have the private keys under my servers?

Comment: A lot of these questions are really best answered by someone with cryptography knowledge. The underlying reasons deal with the difference between pseudorandom and random generation of data, the entropy of the resulting private keys, and the possibility of interception of the private key. The safest would be for users to remember their private key themselves, or encrypt the key using their password when it's stored in the DB.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on encryption, although it's already making my head ache a bit, I know pretty much nothing. I'm already encrypting user passwords with bcrypt, so as a newbie guess, I'm thinking that I might as well do the same with the private keys. The site is for people whom I don't expect to be very tech-savvy, so I guess asking them to remember their private keys would be quite annoying for them (the users). I'm thinking that I might as well generate a wallet with something like Electrum, and use that for all users. Don't know if that'd be a good idea. Thank you for the ideas!

Comment: The private key has to be retrievable, otherwise the wallet is dead and the bitcoins are lost forever. Likewise, don't store your users' coins in a collective wallet as that defeats the point of the individual wallets.